# creating ubuntu service to run a flask app on gunicorn / nginx not working

Tags: permissions, nginx, flask

I have loaded a flask app (appserver.py) on ubuntu 20.04 with nginx & gunicorn. This is running on a virtualbox VM on my desktop.
I can run the app successfully on a terminal session on ubuntu by running:

```
gunicorn appserver
```

I have tried to create a service for this app so that it runs automatically on boot:

1. created file: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appserver`

```
server{  
listen 8001;  
server_name 192.168.68.105;  
location / {  
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  
}  
}
```

2. created the service file: `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]  
Description=Gunicorn service  
After=network.target  

[Service]  
User=afshin  
Group=www-data  
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/appserver/appserver  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:__init__.sock m 007 __init__
```

---

`sudo nginx -t`  -  shows the file format is correct

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo service gunicorn start`

`sudo service gunicorn status` - shows service is active

when I access the site I get 502 Bad Gateway error on the web page.

- nginx error file shows:

```
2021/07/11 20:38:41 [error] 3588#3588: *38 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.68.120, server: 192.168.68.105, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.68.105:8001", referrer: "http://192.168.68.105:8001/"
```

I set the ownership for all files in appserver to www-data:www-data - I've tried 777 permissions on all files to get it working but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: thanks - what are backticks?

Comment: It is a symbol on your keyboard. Use the edit link to review the formatting of this post for an example or search "backtick" in your favorite search engine